# How to throw error while receiving different data type from api

Tags: angular, model

How to throw error when server is sending you different data type as compared to model which is created on client side.
filename - service.ts

```
  getUserData(): Observable<User1> {
        let api_url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/tnick';
           return this.http.get(api_url).pipe(
            map((response: Response) => response.json()),
            map(({userid, terms_status}) => new User1(userid, terms_status))
          );
      }
```

filename - app.component.ts

```
 getData() {
      const data = this.userService.getUserData().subscribe(res => {
      });
    }
```

filename - model.ts

```
export class User1 {

  constructor(public userid: Number,public terms_status: Number
  ) {}
  }
```

so in response I am getting userid as string but in model i have define it as number, So it should throw error but it is not throwing data type error and also I am sending more than two parameters still it accepting the response.I am making mistake in mapping response to model.Please give me proper solution for this.

Comment: Actally what typescript does, is shows error while you write code of types mismatch but it doesn't stop the compiler to compile the code to plain javascript and if you see in compiled javascript code there are no interfaces out there, which actually are not in javascript, in the end you are writing javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use type casting as below:

```
getUserData(): Observable<User1> {
    let api_url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/tnick';
       return this.http.get(api_url).pipe(
        map((response: Response) => response.json()),
        map(({userid, terms_status}) => new User1(Number(userid), Number(terms_status)) )
      );
}
```

If you want to throw error if datatype mismatches. 
Compare the data type and throw error as below:

```
throw new Error("Data type should be same !");
```